# How to make ClearType looks ok even with large fonts

Tags: fonts, rendering, cleartype, anti-aliasing

I discovered that on large/huge fonts ClearType does have a negative impact. Just take a look at http://patterns.dataincubator.org/book/ page (check title with huge fonts versus normal text). If you are on Windows 7 you can use Win+Plus/Minus to zoom in/out.

I'm looking for a configuration that would make both small fonts and large fonts look well. The system is Windows 7 but I suppose you could replicate the problem on Vista and even XP if you activate ClearType.

Current results:

- ClearType on and tunned - small fonts looking good and large one looking bad
- ClearType off - small fonts looking bad and large one looking ok (smoothed)

Just for fun I observed that there is way to activate [OS X like font rendering on Windows](http://lifehacker.com/5190607/gdi%252B%252B-adds-os-x-font-rendering-to-windows) but they are too smooth.

Comment: The page with huge fonts looks perfect to me (even when zoomed in), using the default ClearType tuning on Windows 7. If you can post a screenshot, perhaps we can get a hint at what's wrong.

Comment: It’s impossible. Red pill or blue pill. Being serious, that’s probably just bad hinting.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [Cleartype tuner](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/cleartype/tuner/step1.aspx) ?